# Definition of simple linear algebraic group

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

Why is it that many sources define simple (or almost-simple) linear algebraic group $G/k$ to be a connected, *semisimple* linear algebraic group such that every proper connected normal subgroup is trivial? Doesn't semisimplicity follow from the last condition?

I am told by a friend that part of the issue may be that semisimplicity is defined over $\overline{k}$, whereas simplicity is defined over $k$. Would it then do to define matters as follows?

"A linear algebraic group $G/k$ is *semisimple* if $G$ has no connected, non-trivial, abelian normal algebraic subgroup. It is said to be *simple* if it is semisimple and connected and has no connected, non-trivial normal algebraic subgroup defined over $k$."

I've heard from other friends that there are issues involving non-reduced varieties (but I am using classical foundations...) or non-perfect fields. Does defining simple algebraic groups on top of semisimple algebraic groups take care of such issues, or at least the second one (non-perfect fields)?

Comment: Context:  I am polishing up a set of lecture notes for publication, and I want to get everything precisely right so that I don't lie to the young (in print).

Comment: What is an example of a source that makes this definition?

Comment: Also, if you want to allow your subgroups to be defined not-necessarily-over-$k$, then you must say so explicitly, rather than by omission; I believe the consensus is that proper formal language will have "subgroup of $G$" (where $G$ is defined over $k$) mean "subgroup defined over $k$", whereas for the more general kind of subgroup you'll want to say "subgroup of $G_{\overline k}$" or similar.

Comment: The above is a possibly bowdlerized version of what can be found in different sections of Borel's Linear Algebraic Groups. The definition on Wikipedia is similar.

Comment: In Springer's book there's a 2-dimensional example of a non-reductive (abelian) $k$-group (for $k$ not perfect) with no nontrivial connected unipotent subgroup defined over $k$ (while the unipotent radical is 1-dimensional). It's indeed possible that there are similar examples in which there is no nontrivial connected abelian normal subgroup defined over $k$, but not reductive.

Comment: Ah, all right. So, does the definition suggested above (simplicity in terms of $k$ on top of semisimplicity in terms of $\overline{k}$) fix the issue? And is then there no way to avoid mentioning semisimplicity?

Comment: I don't doubt you about the definition, just honestly don't know where to look!  Where does Borel define simple groups?  I find them neither in the table of contents nor in the index.  Semisimplicity is defined in §11.21, but simplicity does not appear to be mentioned there or nearby.

Comment: The point is that absolute definitions are considered as more fundamental. So, when one has a $k$-group, one first considers absolute definitions, and in a second time one considers non-absolute definitions, when one has to. Semisimple is an absolute definition, so we're happy with it. In the mind of this school of algebraic geometry, a $k$-object is a $\bar{k}$-object enriched with some extra-structure.

Comment: LSpice: (almost-k-)simplicity appears in \S 22.8.

Comment: LSpice: another example of a source that make this definition are Malle-Testerman (in the "Notation" page at the very beginning). Humphreys (p 168) does *not* mention semisimplicity. Neither of them mentions a field of definition, so I take they are both working over the algebraic closure. Is there a difference then?

Comment: Good to see that you asked here (and got a more definitive answer). After thinking about it I realized that the subtleties involved made it seem very suitable for MO, given the number of experts here able to answer.

Comment: Yes there's a difference: for instance, $\mathrm{SO}(3,1)$ is $\mathbf{R}$-simple but not simple (= is not absolutely simple). It's 6-dimensional, and has two 3-dimensional connected normal algebraic subgroups, which are swapped by the Galois automorphism of $\mathbf{R}$ (and the only other connected normal algebraic subgroups are $\{1\}$ and the whole group).

Comment: The endless confusions in the question and comments goes away if you use the language of modern (i.e., post 1960) algebraic geometry. Since there is finally a comprehensive book on algebraic groups written in the modern language, there is not much excuse for sticking to the "classical" language.

Comment: ... that book being?

Comment: Algebraic Groups, CUP, 2017. Concerning your question, see Sections 6h and 19a. (In the example 6.48, it is necessary to take p=2; for more general examples, see 25.38.)

Comment: An online draft of Milne's [beautiful book](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/algebraic-groups/48D122BAEC63C2B70304E20F34482C8F) recommended by [@anon](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/314270/definition-of-simple-linear-algebraic-group#comment784855_314270):  http://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/iAG200.pdf .  A more intimidating discussion can also be found in Appendix A of [Conrad, Gabber, and Prasad - Pseudo-reductive groups](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/pseudoreductive-groups/6B68690CCFFEF4F607728A2AB388AA5F).

Answer (score 8):

Here is an example which shows that by omitting the word semisimple in your definition, you end up with a different class of groups.

Let $E/F$ be a finite inseparable field extension. Let H be a simple algebraic group over $E$. Let $G$ be the Weil restriction $\mathrm{Res}_{E/F}H$. Then $G$ has no proper connected normal subgroups and $G$ is not semisimple. $G$ is a standard example of a pseudo-reductive group.

The difference in the above example comes about because seimisimplicity is defined via passing to the algebraic closure, while simplicity is not. Over a perfect field, the geometric radical always descends to a subgroup over the ground field, so there will be no difference over a perfect field. Regarding non-reduced varieties, I think the only thing one needs to say in all of ones definitions is that a subgroup must be a variety in order to avoid infinitesimal subgroup schemes like the kernel of Frobenius.

Comment: I see - thanks. So, if I assume k is perfect, is it really unnecessary to require semisimplicity first? Or is it still necessary, since the non-existence of non-trivial, proper, connected algebraic subgroups over k might not imply the non-existence of non-trivial, proper, connected, abelian algebraic subgroups over the closure $\overline{k}$ of $k$? (Or does it?)

Comment: Yes. If k is perfect, then $\bar{k}/k$ is Galois. Let R be the radical (=maximal normal solvable connected subgroup) of $G_{\bar{k}}$. Then as R is unique, R is stable under the Galois group, so R arises by base change from a subgroup defined over k, which inherits all the right adjectives, so lies in the radical of G over k. This shows that over perfect fields, one does not need to pass to an algebraically closed field to define semisimple (or reductive)